# PyDev with Python 3.3 and pip cannot create Django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pydev, pip

I'm experiencing problem with the PyDev Eclipse plugin.

I have Python3.3, pip, Eclipse Juno, PyDev plugin installed on a Linux machine. I have installed Django 1.5.4 through pip. Now I am trying to create a Django project from Eclipse, but my Django is not found.

I have set properly my Python - Interpreter in Eclipse, I tried adding only pip's `site-package` without `site-package/django` folder, with or without no result. I tried switching to Python 2.7.5 but still no result. I have found similar questions but no solutions were given.

I found out that other people are experiencing the same problem, so I was wondering if this is some kind of PyDev bug and if yes is there any fix. I have experienced the same problem with another machine running Win7.